# http service not starting error 1009

Tags: http, service, runtime-error

I was trying to print a document for one of my games but the page viewer couldn't see the printer so I checked the print spooler service

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc qc spooler
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: spooler
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS (interactive)
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\System32\spoolsv.exe
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : SpoolerGroup
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Print Spooler
        DEPENDENCIES       : RPCSS
                           : http
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc query spooler

SERVICE_NAME: spooler
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  (interactive)
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1068  (0x42c)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

And tried to start it, then this happened

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start spooler
System error 1068 has occurred.

The dependency service or group failed to start.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Ok so I checked the dependencies

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc qc rpcss
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: rpcss
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k rpcss
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : COM Infrastructure
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
        DEPENDENCIES       : RpcEptMapper
                           : DcomLaunch
        SERVICE_START_NAME : NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc query rpcss

SERVICE_NAME: rpcss
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Ok RPCSS is good, next one

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc qc http && sc query http
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: http
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        START_TYPE         : 3   DEMAND_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : system32\drivers\HTTP.sys
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : HTTP Service
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME :

SERVICE_NAME: http
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1009  (0x3f1)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

OK seeing it stopped I tried to start it again

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start http
System error 1009 has occurred.

The configuration registry database is corrupt.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

So I run SFC to try and fix this BUT...

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

A fat lot of help this is, it can't even fix something so inherently wrong...

So this is where I ask the community for help, I don't know what to do past this point. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Side note: I can't play on LAN since this occurred might be related but I'm not sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case, I had a sub-key under 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo` that was missing information. i.e. all the keys such as 0.0.0.0:40015 have values like "AppId","DefaultFlags", etc.
I had one that had no values under this key. I deleted that "empty" key and HTTP was able to start up.

Comment: thank you will try that. I will let you know if it works

Comment: IT WORKS! thank you so very much!  I don't think I've ever been happier to see a windows printer test page

Comment: Thank alot. I was facing IisExpress process error, found that http was fautly. Fixed it with you solution.